# websphere test connection failed java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in callDSRA0010E

Tags: jdbc, websphere

Server 1 : DMGR server (6.1 version)

Server 2 : WAS 6.1 installed and used as a node for application server (ojdbc14.jar file copied into this server)

Server 3: Oracle 10gR2 installed and listeners and tns are setup correctly

What i have done:

1. Created an user (appli_01) in the database wasdb02 resdies at server3.
2. telnet server3 1521 from server2 as well as server1 success.
3. Created a JAAS - J2C authentication alias with alias=sample1 username = appli_01 (database username) password=password of that database user
4. Created a JDBC provider
5. Created a datasource and gave the values as follows

   ```
   JNDI name :jdbc/sample1  
   Component-managed authentication alias : sample1  
   URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@server3:1521:wasdb02
   ```
6. Then saved and sync the changes.

And Finally if i click the test connection i got below error:

The test connection operation failed for data source sampledb on server nodeagent at node server3Node03 with the following exception: java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in callDSRA0010E: SQL State = null, Error Code = 17,433. View JVM logs for further details.

and systemout log is as follows.

```
10/7/13 15:02:00:482 IST] 000011d5 DataSourceCon E   DSRA8040I: Failed to connect to the DataSource.  Encountered "": java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in callDSRA0010E: SQL State = null, Error Code = 17,433
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:145)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:190)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:286)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:250)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:839)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:389)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:557)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:177)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:163)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper$1.run(DSConfigurationHelper.java:1137)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.getPooledConnection(DSConfigurationHelper.java:1132)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.testConnectionForGUI(DSConfigurationHelper.java:2355)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.testConnectionToDataSource2(DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.testConnection(DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.java:460)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:265)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1089)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:971)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DynamicMetaDataImpl.invoke(DynamicMetaDataImpl.java:231)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MetaDataImpl.invoke(MetaDataImpl.java:238)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:833)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1055)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:948)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:338)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:204)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:55)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:680)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:484)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1498)
```

Comment: I used to get that a lot in WebSphere 6.1 and it would only be resolved by restarting the nodeagent and the server processes. That may not be your problem, but it's probably worth a try.

Comment: Hi Disco, Its cool.. after the node agent restart it working nicely..
Thanks a lot for your timely help.

Comment: @Disco3 Consider adding your comment as an answer since it is what solved Christopher's problem, so it is the correct answer to the question. Btw I had this same problem and your solution helped me solve it.

Comment: Good to hear, I've added it below.

Answer (score 4):

I used to get that a lot in WebSphere 6.1 and it would only be resolved by restarting the nodeagent and the server processes. Unfortunately, I never got a chance to diagnose the root cause.

Comment: I experienced the same: restart all nodes and server process is the only way out

Answer (score 0):

We too get the same error. But we noticed the database were down due to that, this error was happened. After started databases, the data sources connected successfully.